# Preview of settings before they take effect

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am building an admin page for my web site that will allow the admin to change small things like background color, fonts and other things that won't effect the layout of the page. I would like to be able to preview the changes in realtime (as they are being made) before writing the values to the database, using php, where they will become permanent. My thinking is that I will bring up the page that is being changed in an  next to a form where selections can be made for the different settings in the page. I would like to use javascript to change the CSS for the content of the  as new selections are made. Is this possible or do I need to be looking in a different direction? I'm worried about not being able to interact with the page inside the . Will that page be part of the DOM, or does it stand on its own? At this time I'm just brainstorming so I dont have any code to look at.

Comment: Please provide further information. How does the admin change the things ?

Comment: If you're just changing the css file that's being loaded that's pretty simple to do. You would just target the default css include for your page (the default theme or whatever) and then you would just change the source url to the url of the other theme. That should do the trick.

Comment: My thoughts are to store all changeable attributes in a MySQL database that are loaded to the CSS file, using php, on page load. Its easy enough to give the admin the options in a web form and then write the new values to the data base. My issue is the preview. I want to load a copy of the page being changed so that changes can be viewed in real time without writing to the database multiple times while the admin tries to figure out what they want.

Comment: So you're storing the css to the database and then compiling it into a css file later on once it gets saved?

Comment: That is my current plan. If there is a better way I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It's entirely possible to do it that way. The place where your code will become tricky is when you need to compile that css file whether it be at runtime or every time the css gets saved. I would go the route of making a few themes and offering a select box that'll switch the active theme.

Comment: Im thinking (and maybe im wrong) that when the page loads the php will query the database and fill in the proper variables in the CSS file. I'm planning on using a .php file for my css, like this <?php

 header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
 
 ?>. Within in this file I will make the necessary database query and insert the proper values into the CSS as needed.

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way. But your load times are going to be hurt and you're going to be using more server resources than needed since I'm assuming this css file won't be modified all that often. You would be better off to cache the css file and save it to your server. Then when someone changes the css, overwrite the css file with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve your desired result is to modify the css for all elements or the specific elements you are wanting to target as seen below.

```js
function font(ele){
  alert("Changed H1 css to "+ele.value);
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.fontFamily=ele.value;
  }
}
function background(ele){
  document.body.style.background=ele.value;
  alert("Changed background color to "+ele.value);
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>This is a header</h1>

H1 Font: <select onchange="font(this)"><option value="Arial">Arial</option><option value="Times">Times</option><option value="Courier">Courier</option></select><br>
Background Color: <select onchange="background(this)"><option value="#C0FFEE">Coffee</option><option value="#C55">CSS</option><option value="#1CE">ICE</option></select>
</body>
```

Comment: Another method would be to apply some classes to your body tag that apply the css you want to change.